# SSL with external static content server

Tags: asp.net, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I have a .Net web application that for performance issues gets all the static data (CSS, Images, JS) from an external server that is on different location and different hosting company.

I want to enable SSL on my site without the users getting a message:
"Page contains both secure and insecure elements"

Does this means I’ll have to get two SSL Certificates one for each server?

If I want the users to continue getting the static content from the external server what other options do I have?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you do need to have SSL Certificate to the other server too

Answer (score 0):

Other option would be **moving all static resources (from external server) under your server** - so all connections would use consistent HTTP/HTTPS schema rather than mixing up secure HTTPS links from your server and insecure HTTP links from external server.